# evolution does not retrieve mails from my gmail account

Tags: evolution

I just downloaded and installed Evolution. After providing the email account details it is not retrieve my mails from the account. How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set it up correctly by following the instructions on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingGmailWithEvolution

Comment: While this technically answers the question, it may be better to add the key points to your answer, in case that link goes dead.

Comment: What do you mean with the link goes dead?
The reason why I prefer giving a link, is that links are usually maintained. If people later bump on this thread with a similar problem, they find the right source and are able to solve their issues. Duplicating documentation isn't a good thing. If you've ever worked in a corporation and had to maintain documentation, you will understand what I mean with this.